# Storage folder images not displaying in view

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-8

Please how can I display the images stored in storage folder in my view in laravel
Here is my controller;

```
 if ($request->file('image')) {
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $filename = date('YmdHi').$file->getClientOriginalName();
        Image::make($file)->resize(248,203)->save(storage_path('upload/category/'.$filename));
        $data['image'] = $filename;
    }
    $data->save();
```

And here is my view blade

```
<img src="{{Storage::url('upload/category'.$category->image) }}" alt="" width="100">
```

I have runned php artisan storage:link but still the image is not displaying.
Is there any thing else I was supposed to do.

Comment: What does `$category->image` contain? Are you maybe missing an ending slash in `'upload/category'`, which is there when saving the image?

Comment: What's the URL output on your browser? Likely that it's URL issue

Comment: This is my browser URL http://127.0.0.1:8000/category/view. I tried changing my .env APP_URL from APP_URL=http://localhost to APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000 but that did also did not display the image

Comment: And Also I just added the ending slash. think I deleted that out of frustration thou. but it's still not displaying in my view. the $category->image contains the image name from the database

Comment: Is the image present in your file system? Can you check using `ls`? And if $category->image contains just the file name, then try adding `Storage::url('upload/category/'.$category->image)` (Slash after the category directory

Comment: @EMMANUELTSWAM First check that file uploaded into the `upload/category'` folder. 
If file is present with the same name in the database then access file like `<img src="{{Storage::url('upload/category/'.$category->image) }}" alt="" width="100"> `

Comment: The file is present in the upload/category folder with the same name as in the database. And I have also added the ending slash like this {{Storage::url('upload/category/'.$category->image) }}  but it's still not working. Is there something I else I am supposed to do? Thank you all for your help

Comment: Does the image also contain the file extension? can you try doing `dd(Storage::url('/upload/category/'.$category->image)` ?

Comment: When I do this    $data->image = $request->file('image')->store('public/files'); and this in my view <img src="{{Storage::url($category->image) }}" alt="" width="100">   it worked but this is without the intervention/image package. However I would really love to use the intervention Image package. Please any help would be apprecaited.

Answer (score 2):

use this code to link storage public directory to app public directory

`php artisan storage:link`

Then you can access to it's directories or file with this url

`http://yoursite.com/storage/.....`

You can use this code to get files that exist in this folder

`assets('upload/category')`

Comment: When I use this  $data->image = $request->file('image')->store('public/files');  and this in my view <img src="{{Storage::url($category->image) }}" alt="" width="100"> it works but I would really love to use image intervention package. Please help. Thank you for the efforts so far

Comment: Read this article. it might be helpful
https://image.intervention.io/v2

Answer (score 0):

First Create a symbolic link with your public folder by running this command:
php artisan storage:link

After That in view file fetch the image like this.

```
 <img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$category->image) }}" width="100" alt="">
```

Comment: I just don't know have any other person gotten same experience. I have dd the image the path is right the name is same as the name of image in the folder and database but image still refuse to display even after tthe storage:link command

Answer (score 0):

Okay Thank you all for your help. I finally got it right. Let me drop it here might be of help to someone else. I am using laravel 8
so in my controller i used

```
if ($request->file('image')) {
    $file = $request->file('image');
    $filename = date('YmdHi').$file->getClientOriginalName();
    Image::make($file)->resize(248,203)- 
  >save(storage_path('app/public/category/'.$filename));
    $data['image'] = $filename;
    }
   $data->save();
```

and in my view

```
<img src="{{Storage::url('category/'.$category->image) }}" alt="" 
 width="100">
```

NOTE: the directory path is storage>app>public (all these ones are there by default dont create them at least for me) I just had to create the category directory only making it like this

STORAGE>APP>PUBLIC>CATEGORY

and it worked. Thank you all once more for your help so far